# How do I style my table and display inputs horizontally (also need style advice)

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am pulling some data from a database and displaying it as a table using ngfor. There are some style problems. How do I put space between cells in rows?

Another problem is how do I align CRN inputs horizontally?

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWSXL.png)

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 20px;">CRN</td>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Name</td>
          <td style ="font-size: 20px;" >Lecturer</td>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Level</td>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Days</td>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Time</td>
      </tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of courseData">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-decoration: underline;" (click)="crnClicked(data.crn)">{{data.crn}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.lecturer}}</td>
        <td>{{data.level}}</td>
        <td>{{data.days}}</td>
        <td>{{data.hours}}</td>

        <button ion-button small  round (click)="addCrn(data.crn)" color="primary" block>+</button>
    </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
<div class="row">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="CRN1" type ="number" [(ngModel)]="crn1"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="CRN2" type ="number" [(ngModel)]="crn2"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="CRN3" type ="number" [(ngModel)]="crn3"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="CRN4" type ="number" [(ngModel)]="crn4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="CRN5" type ="number" [(ngModel)]="crn5"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

only style inputs has is display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

For the cell spacing, use the CSS `border-spacing` property on the `<table>`, like this:

`<table style="border-spacing: 1rem">...`

As for aligning the CRNs horizontally, you can add `display: flex` to your `row` class:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: yes both part are not working.i mean display:flex made it same vertically ordered

Comment: See if adding `flex-direction: row` fixes it. Do you have any stylesheets elsewhere on the page that could be overriding these?

Comment: i am using ionic maybe thats why.this didnt change too

Comment: You could wrap each `<ion-item>` in a `<div>`. That should get the flexbox styles to work.

Comment: thanks that worked.what about the table spaces ? its still same

Comment: Try adding padding to the table cells like this:
`table td { padding 1rem; }`